# extracting numeric values from the URL

Tags: regex, coldfusion

i have the following code where i want to extract all the values of the specific URL, i tried using rereplacenocase but no help

```
http://example.com/1.asp?type=298&companyQ=148&companyQ=150&companyQ=176&companyQ=186&productQ=1072&productQ=1042&productQ=1043
```

i want to extract all the numeric values of the `companyQ` in a comma seperated value, how can i get that

tried like this

```
<cfloop list="#myurl#" index="k">
    <cfset getcompanyID = ListAppend(k,'&')>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Do you mean your CFML code has a string containing that URL, and you need to parse-out values from the string, or is that the URL of your request (ie: a user has browsed to that URL), and you want all the values of the `companyQ` params passed to the request? And which version of ColdFusion are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly would be more elegant way to do it and definitively more than one way to do so. I assume the url is not the actual application url but a variable (URL scope can be handled bit better)

```
<cfset myurl="http://example.com/1.asp?type=298&companyQ=148&companyQ=150&companyQ=176&companyQ=186&productQ=1072&productQ=1042&productQ=1043">
<cfset getCompanyID="">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list="#myurl#" index="i" delimiters="&">

   <cfif i contains "companyQ">
     <cfset x=ListGetAt(i,2,"=")>
     <cfset getCompanyID=ListAppend(getCompanyID,x)>
   </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>

<cfdump var="#getCompanyID#">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution to your problem.

```
<cfset myurl="http://example.com/1.asp?type=298&companyQ=148&companyQ=150&companyQ=176&companyQ=186&productQ=1072&productQ=1042&productQ=1043">
<cfset urlstring = listLast(myurl,"?")>
<cfset ids = rereplace(arrayToList(rematch("companyQ=[0-9]*", urlstring)),"companyQ=","","all")>
<cfdump var="#ids#">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following (a general solution for any url parameter name). Note the use of the regex word boundary `\b` in `REMatchNoCase()` to prevent the capture of parameters like `acompanyQ`, etc.

```
<cfset the_param_name = "companyQ" />
<cfset the_url = "http://example.com/1.asp?type=298&companyQ=148&companyQ=150&companyQ=176&companyQ=186&productQ=1072&productQ=1042&productQ=1043" />
<cfset the_match = REMatchNoCase("\b#the_param_name#=[^&]+", the_url) />
<cfset the_value_list = replaceNoCase(arrayToList(test), "#the_param_name#=", "", "all") />
<cfdump var="#the_value_list#" />
```

If you want to get fancy you can use Java regular expressions instead (using lookbehind to make sure you get only the correct parameter's values):

```
<cfset param_pattern = createObject("java", "java.util.regex.Pattern").compile("(?i)(?<=[&?]#the_param_name#=)[^&]+") />
<cfset param_match = param_pattern.matcher(the_url) />
<cfset the_value_list = "" />
<cfloop condition="param_match.find()">
    <cfset the_value_list = len(the_value_list) ? the_value_list & ",#param_match.group()#" : "#param_match.group()#" />
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#the_value_list#" />
```